# My form is submitting when the T&C checkbox is ticked even when errors are present elsewhere in the form

Tags: php

I have currently tried having an if(count($count) = 0)){ then SQL inject... submit form.... }  but then I realised that the form would never submit if there was an error because the count would always be greater than 0. I have tried other things but I do not know how to solve this problem. What would be the best way to combat this problem? Thanks.

```
<?php

        $errors = array('firstname' =>' ', 'firstnameMatch' =>' ', 'surname' =>' ', 'surnameMatch' =>' ', 'email' =>' ', 'emailMatch' =>' ', 'username' =>' ', 'passwordMatch' =>' ', 'checkbox' =>' ');
        $count;

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

            if(empty($_POST['firstname'])){
                //echo 'Your missing a First Name! <br>';
                $errors['firstname'] = 'Your missing a First Name!';
                $count++;
            }

            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['firstname'])) {
               // echo 'Ensure that your First Name only contains letters!';
                $errors['firstnameMatch'] = 'Ensure that your First Name only contains letters!';
            }  

            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['surname'])) {
               // echo 'Ensure that your Surname only contains letters!';
                $errors['surnameMatch'] = 'Ensure that your Surname only contains letters!';
            }

            if(empty($_POST['surname'])){
               // echo 'Your missing a Surname! <br>';
                $errors['surname'] = 'Your missing a Surname!';
            }

            if(empty($_POST['email'])){
               // echo 'Your missing a Email! <br>';
                $errors['email'] = 'Your missing a Email!';
            }

            if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
               // echo 'Ensure that you have entered a valid Email Address! e.g: john@gmail.com';
                $errors['emailMatch'] = 'Ensure that you have entered a valid Email Address! e.g: john@gmail.com';
            }

            if(empty($_POST['username'])){
                //echo 'Your missing a Username! <br>';
                $errors['username'] = 'Your missing a Username!';
            }

            if(empty($_POST['password'])){
               // echo 'Your missing a Password! <br>';
                 $errors['password'] = 'Your missing a Password!';
            }

            /*else if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
                // 'Your Password must be greater than 6 characters!';
                $errors['passwordLength'] = 'Your missing a Password!';
            }*/

            if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,12}$/', $_POST['password'])) {
             // echo 'the password does not meet the requirements!';
                $errors['passwordMatch'] = 'Ensure that your password meets the requirements above!';
    }

            if (!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
               // echo 'Ensure that you have read the Terms and Conditions and ticked the box!';
                $errors['checkbox'] = 'Ensure that you have read the Terms and Conditions and ticked the box!';
            }

            else {

                include '../php/connection.php';

                $fname= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['firstname']);
                $sname= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['surname']);
                $age= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['age']);
                $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
                $user= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
                $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

                $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $query="INSERT INTO customer (USER_TYPE, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, AGE, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES 
                (NULL, '$fname', '$sname', '$age', '$email', '$user', '$hashed_password')";

                mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                header('location: login.php');
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean 
`if(count($count) === 0` 
not 
`if(count($count) = 0`
? Because the second one will return error.

> I have currently tried having an if(count($count) = 0)){ then SQL inject... submit form.... } but then I realised that the form would never submit if there was an error because the count would always be greater than 0.

Count variable increments only when you didn't fill the firstname field. Isn't it the reason we use some kind of form validation? You rather don't want to submit form if there are any errors. Maybe I didn't understand correctly what you want to achieve.

Try this:

```
<?php

$errors = array(
    'firstname' => ' ',
    'firstnameMatch' => ' ',
    'surname' => ' ',
    'surnameMatch' => ' ',
    'email' => ' ',
    'emailMatch' => ' ',
    'username' => ' ',
    'passwordMatch' => ' ',
    'checkbox' => ' '
);
$count = 0;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        //echo 'Your missing a First Name! <br>';
        $errors['firstname'] = 'Your missing a First Name!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['firstname'])) {
        // echo 'Ensure that your First Name only contains letters!';
        $errors['firstnameMatch'] = 'Ensure that your First Name only contains letters!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['surname'])) {
        // echo 'Ensure that your Surname only contains letters!';
        $errors['surnameMatch'] = 'Ensure that your Surname only contains letters!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['surname'])) {
        // echo 'Your missing a Surname! <br>';
        $errors['surname'] = 'Your missing a Surname!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        // echo 'Your missing a Email! <br>';
        $errors['email'] = 'Your missing a Email!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // echo 'Ensure that you have entered a valid Email Address! e.g: john@gmail.com';
        $errors['emailMatch'] = 'Ensure that you have entered a valid Email Address! e.g: john@gmail.com';
        $count++;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        //echo 'Your missing a Username! <br>';
        $errors['username'] = 'Your missing a Username!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        // echo 'Your missing a Password! <br>';
        $errors['password'] = 'Your missing a Password!';
        $count++;
    }

    /*else if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
        // 'Your Password must be greater than 6 characters!';
        $errors['passwordLength'] = 'Your missing a Password!';
    }*/

    if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,12}$/', $_POST['password'])) {
        // echo 'the password does not meet the requirements!';
        $errors['passwordMatch'] = 'Ensure that your password meets the requirements above!';
        $count++;
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        // echo 'Ensure that you have read the Terms and Conditions and ticked the box!';
        $errors['checkbox'] = 'Ensure that you have read the Terms and Conditions and ticked the box!';
        $count++;
    }

    if(!$count)

        include '../php/connection.php';

        $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['firstname']);
        $sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['surname']);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['age']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $query = "INSERT INTO customer (USER_TYPE, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, AGE, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES 
                (NULL, '$fname', '$sname', '$age', '$email', '$user', '$hashed_password')";

        mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        header('location: login.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When the checkbox is  checked with all the other fields empty (which should prompt an error) the form submits and puts blank fields into my database.

Comment: You don't have any code which will check if there are any errors. You check only if T&C checkbox is checked.

``` if (!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){```

This is only one of there validation criteria. Add that one which you tried – 
```if(count($count))
{
// THERE ARE SOME ERRORS
}
else{
// INSERT TO DATABASE
}```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to tell me? I do have code to check for errors which it does fine. It's just that I have the code formatted incorrectly so if the checkbox is selected it submits the form. I just don't know how to format the code correctly.

Comment: Where is the condition which check if there are any errors? I just can see condition which check whether checkbox is checked or not (```if (!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){```). So if the checkbox is checked, you will always insert data to database. Event if your other fields are empty.

Can you write one more time – what excatly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I've added to my answer code with my changes. Please check it out.

Comment: Hi. That fixed my problem. Thanks. I did have it right to begin with but my logic was that if there ever was an error and the count was set to something greater than 0 then it wouldn't submit the form. Thanks.

Comment: @ZoomingZoomZoomer  Glad I could help :)